# I want to make my cards in my html side by side but it seems i cant do that . Doing a prototype and want cards next to each other with css

Tags: css

two cards want one card next to the other. different classes and need css to make them side by side.
two cards want one card next to the other. different classes and need css to make them side by side.
two cards want one card next to the other. different classes and need css to make them side by side.

```
        <h2 class="price-head">A Plan for Every Shopper's Needs</h2>
        <p class="price-head">Simple and affordable price plans for you!</p>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-next">Shirts</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        <h2  class="price-text">Graphic Tees</h2>
        <p>Inspiration</p>
        <p>Solid Colored</p>
        <p>Fitness Tees</p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark"type="button">Explore</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-next">Pants</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="price-text">Low priced</h2>
        <p>Chino pants</p>
        <p>Sweats</p>
        <p>Business Casual</p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark" type="button">Try Out!</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


    </section>
```

Comment: why not use boostrap card class?  It makes your life much easier

Comment: @haarun-hussein please add complete HTML, CSS that you tried with the error you facing

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the two divs with the class `row` in another container as follows

```
<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-next">Shirts</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="price-text">Graphic Tees</h2>
                    <p>Inspiration</p>
                    <p>Solid Colored</p>
                    <p>Fitness Tees</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark" type="button">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-next">Pants</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="price-text">Low priced</h2>
                    <p>Chino pants</p>
                    <p>Sweats</p>
                    <p>Business Casual</p>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark" type="button">Try Out!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add CSS styling to `row-container` as follows

```
.row-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row
}
```